# C++ lambda function as class member: strange behaviour

Tags: c++, class, methods, lambda, field

I have a class where I would like to use lambda function (for example, just write a value of public member). Lambda is keeped in the std::function object:

```
class Tester
{

public:

    Tester() {};
    Tester(double val);
    ~Tester() {}

    //- variable
    double v;

    //- write v using lambda
    std::function<void()> writeV;

    //- write v using simple function
    void writeVexp();
};

Tester::Tester(double val)
{
    v = val;

    writeV = [this]() { std::cout << "inside lambda " << v << '\n'; };
}

void Tester::writeVexp()
{
    std::cout << "inside simple function " << v << '\n';
}
```

I have another class which collects these testers in std::vector:

```
class vectorTester
{
    std::vector<Tester> vtst;

    double size;

public:

    //- default constructor
    vectorTester() {}

    //- construct by number of testers
    vectorTester(double num);

    ~vectorTester() {}

    //- write publuc members of all Testers 
    void useTesterLambda();
    void useTesterSimple();
    void useTesterVar();
};

vectorTester::vectorTester(double num)
{
    vtst.reserve(num);

    size = num;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        Tester tst (i + 0.365);
        vtst.push_back(tst);
    }
}


void vectorTester::useTesterLambda()
{
    cout << "\n tester's lambda \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        vtst[i].writeV();
    }
}

void vectorTester::useTesterSimple()
{
    cout << "\n tester's simple function \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        vtst[i].writeVexp();
    }
}

void vectorTester::useTesterVar()
{
    cout << "\n tester's vars \n";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        cout << vtst[i].v << endl;
    }
}
```

And the main function is simple:

```
int main()
{
    vectorTester vtst(5);

    vtst.useTesterLambda();
    vtst.useTesterSimple();
    vtst.useTesterVar();

    return 0;
}
```

The output said me that lambda function can not see the value V of class Tester!

```
     tester's lambda 
inside lambda 0
inside lambda 4.94066e-324
inside lambda 9.88131e-324
inside lambda 1.4822e-323
inside lambda 1.97626e-323

 tester's simple function 
inside simple function 0.365
inside simple function 1.365
inside simple function 2.365
inside simple function 3.365
inside simple function 4.365

 tester's vars 
0.365
1.365
2.365
3.365
4.365
```

What is the reason of this strange behaviour?

Comment: If the vector `vtst` has to reallocate the captured `this` pointer is left hanging.  `Tester` indirectly contains a pointer to it's own instance and you have broken the rule of 3 or 5.

Comment: use `[v]() { cout << v << "\n";}`.

Comment: @qdbp it's better to not use endl if you don't want to flush the stream explictly

Comment: @UKMonkey: ok, thanks

Comment: @qdbp two compiler errors: capture of non-variable Tester::v; 'this' was not captured in this lambda function

Comment: Ah, I didn't recognize `v` was a member of the class. Then I would try `[this]() {... this->v ...}`

Comment: replace `Test tst(i+0.365); vtst.push_back(tst);` by `vtst.emplace_back(i+0.365)` , whatsoever if you copy your vector, you will get the error again.

Comment: @Oliv it helps))) thanks so much!

Comment: @qdbp doesn't help... I found one solution: auto vv = this->v; writeV = [vv]() {cout << vv << endl;} but I have no idea why it works =)

Comment: @Darksy: But it is no longer bound to member. (if you change `v`, lambda would still print old value).

Comment: @Darsky, If you plain to maintain your program, you should consider following Jarod42's answer.

Answer (score 0):

As state in comment you have broken rule of 0/3/5, you have to implement copy constructor

```
class Tester
{
public:
    Tester(double val) : v(val) {
        writeV = [this](){std::cout << "inside lambda " << v << '\n';};
    }

    Tester(const Tester& rhs) : v(rhs.v) {
        writeV = [this](){std::cout << "inside lambda " << v << '\n';};
    }

    Tester& operator =(const Tester& rhs) {
        v = rhs.v;
        // Keep function
        return *this;
    }

    void writeVexp() const { std::cout << "inside simple function " << v << '\n'; }
private:
    double v;
    std::function<void()> writeV;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/UgJEAV)